# Remove alpha channel of Mat in opencv android java

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm loading a Mat from a Bitmap using Utils.bitmapToMat(). This produces a matrix with 4 channels. How do I get a matrix with 3 channels, with the alpha channel simply removed?

In other words, I would like the python equivalent of mat[:,:,0:3] in opencv java on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the alpha channel is the last color channel (BGRA or RGBA color format), you may use `Imgproc.cvtColor` with `Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR` argument:

```
// Creating the empty destination matrix
Mat dst_mat = new Mat();

// Converting the image from BGRA to BGR and saving it in the dst_mat matrix
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, dst_mat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
```

---

Note:

- I didn't test the code, but according to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html) and [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-converting-image-grayscale-using-cvtcolor/) the code should work.